# Why is the Möbius strip not a product manifold despite being parameterizable as $(\theta, h)$?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, mobius-band

I was reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0611201)<sup>†</sup> lecture note and came across to the section on fibre bundles. On page 2 they mention that there is *no unambiguous and continuous way* to write a point $m$ on a  Möbius strip $M_0$ as a Cartesian pair $(s,t) \in S^1 \times L$, and therefore conclude that the Möbius strip is *not* a product manifold globally. However, [in this Quora answer](https://qr.ae/TeA6ES) an explicit parameterization of the Möbius strip in terms of $(\theta, h)$ is shown where $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$ and $h\in [-1, 1]$ i.e.,

$$\displaystyle(X(\theta,h),Y(\theta,h),Z(\theta,h)) = (\cos(\theta)\left(R+h\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})\right),\sin(\theta)\left(R+h\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})\right),h\sin(\frac{\theta}{2}))$$

Could someone clarify this apparent contradiction?

---

<sup>†: Topology of Fibre bundles and Global Aspects of Gauge Theories (Andres Collinucci & Alexander Wijns, 2006) [arXiv:hep-th/0611201]</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explicit parameterization you've given has different values when $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = 2\pi$. Thus, while's it's a continuous map from $[0, 2\pi] \times L$ to the Möbius strip, it doesn't descend to a continuous map from $S^1 \times L$ to the Möbius strip.

Comment: Thanks! Minor confusion: why would a continuous map from $S^1\times L$ to the Mobius strip necessarily *require* the explicit parameterization to attain the same value at $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = 2 \pi$?

Comment: The circle $S^1$ is obtained from the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ by gluing $0$ and $2\pi$ together; that is, $0$ and $2\pi$ represent the same point in $S^1$. Since there's really the same point, they have to map to the same place.

Comment: I have not read completely the Quora answer you posted but the point of the parametrization  proposed there is to give a continuous function whose image is an embedded Moebius strip in $\mathbb{R}^3$. While in the paper of Collinucci and Wijins they want to say that you cannot find a diffeomorphism between the strip and $S^1 \times L$ (which boils down to the fact that the Moebius strip is non orientable). They are referring to two different types of parametrizations.